# Filtering and searching for strings by array_filter() function

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, array-filter, string-function

I have a list of people's names and ages. Through function array_filter(), I can filter people who are over 40 years old, which returns the correct answer
But if I want to put a filter for the names of people, this issue does not work properly through the Strpos() function, for example, if I want to write the phrase **sapi**, the answer should include the names **sapi** and **rahmatsapi**, but the answer is not like that. I tried other functions such as the strpbrk() function, but they did not give the right answer.

```
$listL = [
['name' => 'sapi', 'age' => 49],
['name' => 'rahmatsapi', 'age' => 42],
['name' => 'neko', 'age' => 39]];

$filterUser = array_filter($listL, fn($user) => $user['age'] > 40);

$filterUser = array_filter($listL, fn($user) => strpos($user['name'], 'sapi'));

var_dump($filterUser);
```

If I definitely want to use array_filter()function and string functions, what is the correct way? If string functions do not have such capability, what is the alternative solution?
Thanks

Comment: Check the big red box in the docs for [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here in my test it work.  I believe that is cause strpos need be check with === rather then ==

```
$listL = [
['name' => 'sapi', 'age' => 49],
['name' => 'rahmatsapi', 'age' => 42],
['name' => 'neko', 'age' => 39]];

 $filterUserAge = array_filter($listL, function ($user){
    if($user['age'] > 40){
    return $user;
  }
});

$filterUserName = array_filter($listL, function($user){
$pos = strpos($user['name'], 'sapi');
$achou =false;

if($pos === false){
    return $achou;
}else{
   $achou = true;
    return $user;
 }
});

print_r($filterUserName);
```

Regards